# Using Apache POI in eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I am trying to develop an applicatio which needs to create,read and modify Excel sheets.So I have downloaded  poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.tar.gz from http://poi.apache.org/download.html .
I have followed this procedure to create the project.

I have created a new java project named ApacheDemo.
Right clicked the project ->  Import -> General -> Existing Projects into workspace -> Select Archive file and browsed to the .tar.gz file .

But it shows me "No projects are found to import"

I have googled and tried an another method

RIghtclick on project-> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add external Jar ->  browsed to poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208

This dint work too.Please Help me.

Comment: what is the project that you tried to import?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the files from `poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.tar.gz`.

Then you will will have two directories `lib` and `ooxml-lib` containing `jar` files. Add the `jar` files you need to eclipse...

There are also `jar` files above the `lib` directory. You will need some of these as well.

Comment: Do i have to add all the jar files in these two folders?

Comment: Then you need to explain your question more clearly. What exactly are you trying to do? What is still not working? What is the exact error message? Please update the original question and make sure to include the information you have managed to add the jars.

Comment: when i use import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; ,it shows me an error.

Comment: Ah. I see there are some more `jar` files one directory up from `lib`. You will need these as well, probably `poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar`. If this fixes your issue, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project having build issue `project->properties->java build path->libraries` and check if any jar showing with red color.Remove these from path and add only required jars, and Do the project clean and build it again.

To ensure whether your project is working fine or not you can try to execute a simple "helloworld" programs.
Once its done you will find that import error is automatically gone.